# How do I authenticate proxy server in WinInet for HTTPS?

Tags: delphi, authentication, https, proxy, wininet

According to Microsoft-Support: [How To Handle Proxy Authorization with WinInet](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/195650/how-to-handle-proxy-authorization-with-wininet)
and other Delphi examples (http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51366-internetopen-tthreads-maxconnectionsperserver/, https://pastebin.com/f1ea3a752), I wrote following test code to try out the proper way to access a https page through an authenticated proxy server:

```
program Project35;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, WinInet, Windows, Classes;

Function sslGet(Const AServer, AUrl : string): AnsiString;
var
  aBuffer     : Array[0..4096] of Char;
  BufStream   : TMemoryStream;
  sMethod     : AnsiString;
  BytesRead   : Cardinal;
  pSession    : HINTERNET;
  pConnection : HINTERNET;
  pRequest    : HINTERNET;
  LUsername: string;
  LPassword: string;
  LProxy, LBypass: string;
  LAgent: string;
  LStatusCode, LStatusLen, LIndex : DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  LUsername := 'User-002' ;
  LPassword := 'test2';
  LProxy := 'myproxyserver:808';//https=https://
  LBypass := '<local>';
  LAgent := 'Bo-Test';
//pSession := InternetOpen(PChar(LAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, nil, nil, 0);
  pSession := InternetOpen(PChar(LAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY , PChar(LProxy), PChar(LBypass), 0);
//pSession := InternetOpen(PChar(LAgent), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY , nil,  nil, 0);

  if Assigned(pSession) then
  try

//    pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(AServer), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, PChar(LUsername), PChar(LPassword), INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
  pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(AServer), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);

    if Assigned(pConnection) then
    try

      sMethod := 'GET';
      pRequest := HTTPOpenRequest(pConnection, PChar(sMethod), PChar(AURL), nil, nil, nil,
                    INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI or
                    INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS or
                    SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA, 0); //or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH

      if Assigned(pRequest) then
      try

        if HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil,  0, nil, 0) then
        begin
          LStatusLen := SizeOf(LStatusCode);
          LIndex := 0;
          // expecting a 407 returned
          HttpQueryInfo(pRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
          @LStatusCode, LStatusLen, LIndex);
          Write('Status code=');
          writeln(LStatusCode);

          // resend after 407
          InternetSetOption(pRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME, PChar(LUsername) , length(LUsername));
          InternetSetOption(pRequest, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD, PChar(LPassword), length(LPassword));
          HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil,  0, nil, 0);
          HttpQueryInfo(pRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE or HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
          @LStatusCode, LStatusLen, LIndex);
          Write('Resend status code=');
          writeln(LStatusCode);

          BufStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
          try

           while InternetReadFile(pRequest, @aBuffer, SizeOf(aBuffer), BytesRead) do
             begin
               if (BytesRead = 0) then Break;

               BufStream.Write(aBuffer, BytesRead);
             end;

             aBuffer[0] := #0;
             BufStream.Write(aBuffer, 1);
             Result := PChar(BufStream.Memory);

          finally
           FreeAndNil(BufStream);
          end;
        end
        else begin
          Writeln(GetLastError());
        end;

      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(pRequest);
      end;

    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(pConnection);
    end;

  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(pSession);
  end;
end;

var
  StopEnter: string;
begin
  try
    // the wsdl is only available with ssl, i.e., https://services.staging.referralnet.com.au/services/Referral_Service_51?wsdl
    // it is invalid for http://services.staging.referralnet.com.au/services/Referral_Service_51?wsdl
    Writeln(sslGet('services.staging.referralnet.com.au', '/services/Referral_Service_51?wsdl'));
    Write('Press Enter to stop ...');
    Readln(StopEnter);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I am using CCProxy as the proxy server for this testing.
I tried with two machines, one modified the hosts file so that the server of the wsdl page is pointing to 127.0.0.1, another one modified its firewall, so all the traffic to the server is blocked.

Both testings returned two 407 code, i.e., original and resend request both failed with 407.

What could be wrong? Or somebody can point me to an working example?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how the THttpRIo component handles this. Just follow the proxy property usage in the code.

Comment: Actually, my original full version code was based on SOAPHTTPTrans.pas, one "enhancement" was the flags INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH and INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI as my application is a Windows service. If INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTH is commented out, it then returns 200, but I am not sure if this has any side affect, i.e., any dialog pop up as a part of automatic authentication performed by the WinInet.